# Map not showing anchor with if else

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I made two maps on the same webpage which is suppose to show only one map at a time. (eg. if my location is A then show map1, if location is B then show map2. changing maps work fine. the only problem I have right now is the anchor only appears in one map. Please help.

**My Javascript**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(4.584007, 101.090027);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(3.040517, 101.704167);
        var mapProp2 = {
            center: myLatlng1,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp2);


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Location'
        });
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng1,
            map: map2,
            title: 'Location'
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
<script>
    var originalNavClasses;

    function toggleNav() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('navigation_list');
        var classes = elem.className;
        if (originalNavClasses === undefined) {
            originalNavClasses = classes;
        }
        elem.className = /expanded/.test(classes) ? originalNavClasses : originalNavClasses + ' expanded';
    }
</script>
```

**My If.. Else Statement**

```
%If Request.QueryString("location") = "A" Then %>
        <a href="geo:http://maps.google.com/?q=3.040517,101.704167,15z"><img src="img/button_directions.png" border="0" /></a>
        <%Else %>
        <a href="geo:http://maps.google.com/?q=4.584007,101.090027,15z"><img src="img/button_directions.png" border="0" /></a> 
        <%End If%>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you show only one map at a time, you should really avoid having two maps instances, they are pretty heavy and it can lead to that kind of confusion. Use only one instance changing it's options when required. You can change just about any parameter of a map instance after its initialization.

Right now I see something like that could help you :

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(4.584007, 101.090027);
var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(3.040517, 101.704167);

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title: 'Location'
});

// Then you can set the position of the marker and the center of the map
function changeLocation(someCondition){
  if(someCondition){
      marker.setPosition(myLatlng1);
      map.setCenter(myLatlng1);
  }else{
      marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
      map.setCenter(myLatlng);
  }
}
```

If the wanted behavior is to remember two different map statuses then you can store them

```
var mapPreviousStatus = {
   center: map.getCenter(),
   zoom: map.getZoom(),
   mapTypeId : map.getMapTypeId()
   // Any other parameter that you must remember
};
```

Working this way is a bit more work but is much more efficient.

Refer to the [Google Maps Javascript API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) for [Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) and [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)